# How to add multiple recipients to an xml configuration file and send a mail to those recipients from a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, email

I am trying to retrieve the contents of an URL, filter it based on some conditions and share this filtered result with multiple mail recipients. My mail recipients and smtp settings are present on a xml file. I am calling that xml file from within the power shell script and sending out the e-mail. When the xml file is having only 1 recipient the code works absolutely fine. `

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()
#-------------------------------------------------
#  Variables
#-------------------------------------------------
Start-Transcript
$myDir = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop"
$request='https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=25'
invoke-restmethod -Uri $request | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100  | Out-file C:\Users\abc\Desktop\API_Content.json
$variable=invoke-webrequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json # WE CAN ALSO USE $variable =Get-Content “C:\Users\abc\Desktop\API_Content.json”#
$data=$variable.data | Where-Object {$_.id -ge 7 -and $_.id -le 9}
#$data | Format-List *


# Import email settings from config file

[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "$myDir\Settings.xml"


# Create email content
$smtpsettings = @{

    to = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailTo

    from = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailFrom

    subject = "TEST EMAIL"

    smtpServer = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.SMTPServer

    }

 

[String]$messagebody = ""

#-------------------------------------------------
#  Script
#-------------------------------------------------

try
{
 #Send-MailMessage @smtpsettings -Body $body  -ErrorAction STOP
 $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpsettings.SmtpServer)
 $smtp.Send($smtpsettings.To,$smtpsettings.From, $smtpsettings.Subject, $messagebody)
}

catch
{
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}

#-------------------------------------------------
#  The End
#-------------------------------------------------
```

`When I am adding multiple recipients instead of one recipient to the xml file I am getting the error message:"
WARNING: Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','."

[XML FILE SETTINGS (IGNORE THE SMPTP SERVER NAME)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0aPi.png)

I need to send the message body to 4 recipients instead of 1 keeping the above code and approach intact.

Any kind help is solicited.

Comment: What is the value of `$ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailTo`?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0'?>
<Settings>
 <EmailSettings>
 <SMTPServer>abc@xyz.com</SMTPServer>
 <SMTPPort>25</SMTPPort>
 <MailFrom>abc@xyz.com</MailFrom>
 <MailTo>'you@xyz.com,me@xyz.com'</MailTo>
 </EmailSettings>
</Settings>

Comment: @lit - can you please reply.

Comment: Please see the answer from @Cpt.Whale.

Answer (score 0):

The `Send()` method you're using only accepts a single string as the recipient email address, but it can be a comma-separated list as long as it's still surrounded by quotes.

```sh
$smtpsettings = @{
    to = 'me@domain.com,you@domain.com' # This will work (a single string)
}
$smtpsettings = @{
    to = 'me@domain.com','you@domain.com' # This (a string array) only sends to the last address for some reason
}
```

**But** to get the error you're seeing you probably have an invalid email address in your list or an extra comma:

```sh
$smtpsettings = @{
    to = 'me@domain.com,you@domain.com,' # This will error (a trailing comma)
}

'Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','."'
```

---

Note: ever since powershell v2, you should use `Send-MailMessage` instead. It accepts almost anything for addresses, and can use SSL, smtp credentials, and some other features without much worry:

```sh
Send-MailMessage -From 'me@domain.com' -To @('you@domain.com','me@domain.com') -Body 'Hello World' -SmtpServer 'Mail.domain.com'
```